# Create copies of original workbook inputting new data from list

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy my original worksheet but with different data for as many items in a list/array.

My original worksheet is formatted in such a way it references the cells in the data array worksheet.

For example

`TEST    TIME    Output1     Output2`

```
   A        3         5           9  
   .        .         .           .
   .        .         .           .
   .        .         .           .
   Z        2         9           4
```

Above would be something like my data array worksheet and I would reference the cells to the formatted worksheet. The end result would be 26 worksheets named A test, B test, ..., and Z test.

Is there a way to copy a worksheet over and over creating new reference cells going down an array?

What I have:

```
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim SCHPipe As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MacroTBF1 As Excel.Workbook

Set SCHPipe = ActiveSheet
Set MacroTBF1 = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In SCHPipe.Range("B12:B15")
    With MacroTBF1
   .Sheets("OriginalTBF").Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
   End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

I do not know how to reference the data to each sheet being created. This keeps getting an invalid error message.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that using a macro.  What have you tried, and what specifically is giving you problems with achieving this?

Comment: I am off and on with VBA so my coding is never good. But I am having trouble figuring out, One, how to loop through a array of data. Two, referencing the cells to the newly created sheet.

Comment: Also, what I mean by referencing is say my data is in column "Output1", for each value in the column it will go into a separate worksheet but in the same cell (like B24...). I am trying to do something similar to this persons example...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311844/creating-multiple-worksheets-or-workbooks-from-one-source-worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, you will need to adjust for the layout of your data and template sheet:

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim SCHPipe As Worksheet, shtOrig As Worksheet
    Dim MacroTBF1 As Workbook, shtNew As Worksheet


    Set SCHPipe = ActiveSheet
    Set MacroTBF1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtOrig = MacroTBF1.Sheets("OriginalTBF")


    For Each cell In SCHPipe.Range("B12:B15")

        If cell.Value <> "" Then

            shtOrig.Copy after:=MacroTBF1.Sheets(MacroTBF1.Sheets.Count)
            Set shtNew = MacroTBF1.Sheets(MacroTBF1.Sheets.Count)

            With shtNew
                .Name = cell.Value & " Test"
                .Range("A1").Value = cell.Value
                .Range("A2").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Range("D49").Value = IIf(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "-", _
                                          cell.Offset(0, 5).Value, "")
            End With
        End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It is working! (Thanks) I only need the column B values for the name of each sheet.(Which    .Name = cell.Value & " Test      performs?) I am trying to change the  .Range("A1").Value = cell.Value**      and     ** .Range("A1").Value = cell.Offset(0,1).Value**       portion but having no luck. If I want to use a different value within shtOrig how would I do this? Say I wanted cell F12, would it be       ** =cell.Offset(0,4)**      (From B12)?

Comment: Yes if you want F12 then that's four columns over from B12 on the same row (so first argument is zero)

Comment: I am trying to place an IF statement under (.Range("A2").Value = Cell.Offset(0,1).Value.) Saying if cell C12 in shtOrig equals "-" then place G12 in shtOrig in D49 of new sheet.